# Isomorphism of rings (with parameters)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. For each choice of $a,b\in \mathbb{F}_p,$ let $F(a, b)$ be the ring $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2+aX+b).$ Find all possible choices of $(a, b), (a', b')\in \mathbb F_p \times \mathbb F_p$ such that $F(a, b) \cong F(a', b').$

Comment: For some $a_1,b_1$ we have first ring and for other $a_2,b_2$ we have second.

Comment: I've edited the question. See if it's correct. Is this the question you  asked?

Comment: @Krish, yes - it's correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Whatever $a$ and $b$, the ring will be a $\Bbb F_p$ vector-space of dimension $2$. As ring we have the following three possibilities for the quotient:

- A ring with a unique maximal ideal $\frak m$ such that $\frak m^2=(0)$.
- The ring $\Bbb F_p\times\Bbb F_p$.
- A field with $p^2$ elements.

These situations should be linked to the behaviour of the roots of the polynomial $X^2+aX+b$ to complete the answer.

Note that there's only one finite field of given cardinality up to isomorphism.

Comment: So, if $X^2+aX+b=(X-c)(X-d)$ where $\mbox{gcd}(X-c,X-d)=1$ then $F(a,b)=\mathbb{F}_p\times\mathbb{F}_p$. If $X^2+aX+b$ is irreducible (Eisenstein criterior ?) we have a field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. But when we have the first possibility ?

Comment: If $X^2 + aX + b = (X + c)^2,$ for some $c \in \mathbb F_p$ then the first possibility will occur. For example take $a = b = 0.$